# Which of the following integrals is =0?

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis

$\int_C \bar z dz$ where the curve $C$ is described by $|z|=1$

so the integral of $\bar z=x-iy$, why does it equal zero?

Comment: I've edited your question to have mathematical notation in it, but I'm not sure why you're asking "which of the following", when there's only one integral in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not $0$, actually. Parametrize the curve $C$ by $z=e^{it}$ over $[0,2\pi]$. Then $dz=ie^{it}dt$. So 
$$\int_C \overline{z}\;dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{e^{it}}\;i\; e^{it}dt=i\int_0^{2\pi}1dt=2i\pi.$$

**Note:** that's, equivalently, $\int_C\frac{1}{z}dz=2i\pi$. This is the only case where $\int_Cz^ndz$ is nonzero, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If you remove one point from the circle, you get a complex logarithm, as an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z}$. So your integral computes the variation of the argument along the circle. This tends to $2\pi$ when you tend to the removed point.